# Probability of orthogonal vectors?

Tags: co.combinatorics, linear-algebra, asymptotics, vector-spaces, inner-product

Denote $\mathcal I_m=\{-m,-m+1,\dots,0,\dots,m-1,m\}$ where $m\geq0$ is an integer.

Pick a uniformly random vectors $$\hat a=(a_n,a_{n-1},\dots,a_1)\in(\mathcal I_{m_1}+\sqrt{-1}\cdot\mathcal I_{m_2})^n$$ $$\hat b=(b_n,b_{n-1},\dots,b_1)\in(\mathcal I_{m_1'}+\sqrt{-1}\cdot\mathcal I_{m_2'})^n$$
 ($a_i,b_j$ are uniformly distributed (not gaussian) in a region complex plane) where integers $m_1,m_2,m_1',m_2'$ satisfy $0\leq m_1'\leq m_1$ and $0\leq m_2'\leq m_2$.

What is the probability that $\langle\hat a,\hat b\rangle=0$ holds?

I am not looking for exact answer. I am only looking for sharp asymptotics and approximations.

Comment: For $m_1, m_2$ fixed, $n \rightarrow \infty$  it should be amenable to a local limit theorem.  If interested y0u might browse  Petrov, 'sums of i.I.d random variables'